# Composer installing wrong laravel version

Tags: laravel, composer-php

i have been creating a few Laravel 5.1 and 5.2 projects. 
Now i wanted to try 5.3.

when installing a new project using

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel my-new-project
```

and the project was installed, i noticed this was still a Laravel 5.2 project structure.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of PHP are you running?

Laravel53 uses php >5.6
Composer will fallback to Laravel52 incase you do not have the correct dependancies.

If this does not solve the problem, you can always run the command as such:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.3.0 my-new-project --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also mention the specific version you want by running the following

`composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.3 your-project-name --prefer-dist`